# Weird JNI crash when using FileChannel.transferTo

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, nio

I am using FileChannel.transferTo method to trasnfer bytes from my local file to a network socket. When the other end of the socket closes the connection, either using .close on the channel, or due to some error, I get a very long [JNI error stack-Strace](http://pastebin.com/UZDQYdGC) in my android application.

The parts that I could make sense of are :

1. The crash happens at line :

   fileChannel.transferTo
                               (offset, bytesSize, channel);
2. The error :

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI SetLongField called with
>   pending exception 'android.system.ErrnoException' thrown in long
>   libcore.io.Posix.sendfile(java.io.FileDescriptor,
>   java.io.FileDescriptor, android.util.MutableLong, long):-2

This is the Java code that gets executed after my transferTo call :

> at libcore.io.Posix.sendfile(Native method) at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendfile(BlockGuardOs.java:265) at
>   java.nio.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:431)

From the java source code this is the line 431 in FileChannelImpl

```
try {
MutableLong offset = new MutableLong(position);
long rc = Libcore.os.sendfile(outFd, fd, offset, count); //line 431
completed = true;
return rc;
} catch (ErrnoException errnoException) {
// If the OS doesn't support what we asked for, we want to fall through and
// try a different approach. If it does support it, but it failed, we're done.
if (errnoException.errno != ENOSYS && errnoException.errno != EINVAL) {
throw errnoException.rethrowAsIOException();
}
}
```

From what I understand, an IO exception should have been thrown, because the ErrnoException get "rethrown" as an IOException. Apparently the Mutable-Long is being set while there is a pending exception. Although I doubt this, but is there somehow a way to prevent app crash after this "bug" ?

Comment: BlockGuardOs <= hmmm, seems like NOMTE but from native code :P

Comment: what is NOMTE ? im guessing slang, because Google didn't return anything :P

Comment: my fav exception .. NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: For the time being I have replaced the transferTo with simple buffer read and write. I still android.system.ErrnoException when socket is abruptly closed, but it gets caught.